# How to Declare Plugin in config.xml using Phonegap 2.9

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, cordova-3

I want to use WaitingDialog plugin for my iOS application to show activity indicator. And i'm using PhoneGap 2.9 which is compatible with Xcode 5. I don't know how to declare plugin in PhoneGap 2.9 . Could anybody tell me how the bindings of Plugin take place in PhoneGap 2.9.

**link for plugin:**

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/WaitingDialog

regards,
Varun Mehta

Comment: Hi Guys!! I an following 

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#Configuration%20Reference

But its giving me error "TypeError: 'undefined is not an object (evaluating window.plugins.waitingDialog.show')"

Answer (score 4):

After Searching a lot i find out a solution for my problem and will like to share with others who are still facing it. To show Activity Indicator in your iOS application Using PhoneGap 2.9.0. Follow the below steps:

1. Go to " https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/WaitingDialog " and use this plugin.
2. Go to `<ProjectDirectory>`/config.xml and declare your Plugin

   ```
   <feature name="WaitingDialog">
   <param name="ios-package" value="WaitingDialog" />
   </feature>
   ```
3. Use it in Your JS file as

   ```
   window.plugins.waitingDialog.show("please wait..");
   ```

**PLEASE NOTE:** In PhoneGap 2.9.0 **cordova.plist** has been deprecated to **config.xml** and `<plugins>` tag deprecated to `<feature>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin"/>
</feature>
```